# I expect this elisp function to visualize entire function, but it visualizes beginning to cursor

Tags: emacs, elisp, evil-mode

It looks like the function that I use is not correctly visualizing the entire function. Currently, the function only visually highlights the region from the beginning of the function to the current buffer cursor position.

I want to modify this function to select the function, from top to bottom.

```
(defun evil-visual-current-function ()
  "Highlight the entire current function in Evil's visual mode."
  (interactive)
  (let ((function-name (which-function)))
    (if function-name
        (save-excursion
          (beginning-of-defun)
          (evil-visual-make-selection (point)
          (end-of-defun) (point)))  ; move cursor to end of function
      (message "Not inside a function"))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you leave the `save-excursion` block, the cursor moves back to the original position, which changes the selected region. Change the function to:

```el
(defun evil-visual-current-function ()
  "Highlight the entire current function in Evil's visual mode."
  (interactive)
  (let ((function-name (which-function))
    (if function-name
        (progn
          (beginning-of-defun)
          (evil-visual-make-selection (point) (end-of-defun) (point)))
      (message "Not inside a function"))))
```